# When we say limit in probability, what do we mean?

Tags: limits, statistics

We have a parameter $\theta$ and an estimator $\hat{\theta}$. There are various ways to define consistency, this is one I've seen often.  $\hat{\theta_n}$, where $n$ indexes the sample size, is consistent for $\theta$ if
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P( |\theta - \hat{\theta}| > \epsilon) = 0, \forall \epsilon >0.
$$
Now $\hat{\theta}$ is a random variable with a distribution, so it's a ``spread out'' thing, and I don't see any way for the distribution (even in probability) to equal a single value. Do we mean by this statement that the probability that the difference between **a value** drawn from $\hat{\theta_n}$ and $\theta$ is greater than $\epsilon$ is zero?

If yes, then good, I can understand that. If not, I'm lost.

Comment: Hint.  Compare what happens in the weak law of large numbers.

Comment: An important thing about convergence in probability is that you choose the $\epsilon$ (however small you like) before you take the limit.

Comment: @GEdgar. Thanks for weighing in. Interestingly, both your response and the answer below focus on the concept of consistency rather than the last sentence of the question, so, let me refocus: what is the answer to my question in the last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. A consistent estimator is one whose sampling distribution of $\hat \theta_n$ concentrates more and more about the true parameter value as the sample size grows, with the limiting distribution of $\hat \theta_n$ being that of a "[constant random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20a%20constant,on%20events%20with%20probability%20zero.)".

So, I'd expect that $\hat \theta_{1,000,000}$ would be much less likely to be far from $\theta$ than $\hat \theta_{10}$

More specifically (in response to your comment):

As you pointed out, before we collect a sample, each $\hat \theta_n$ is a random variable with some distribution $\hat \theta_n \sim P_n$.

The mathematical statement:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P( |\theta - \hat{\theta}| > \epsilon) = 0, \forall \epsilon >0.
$$

has four parts:

1. The absolute deviation about some *fixed* value $\theta$, (i.e., $|\theta - \hat{\theta}|$), which is itself a random variable (let's call it $D_n$).
2. $\epsilon > 0$ is some *fixed* positive lower bound we want to use.
3. $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ means we are examining the value of $P(D_n > \epsilon)$ as the sample gets larger.
4. The most important (in my opinion) is the $\forall \epsilon > 0$ which means that not only does the limit hold for particular $\epsilon$ but for *any* arbitrarily small positive $\epsilon$.

Putting all this together, what this means is that when you take a sample of size $n$ you are "drawing" *one* value (say, $y_1$) from the distribution of $\hat \theta_n$ -- $y_1$ will have some actual deviation $d_{n,1}=| y_1- \theta_n|$.

If we repeated this experiment $m$ times, then we'd get a sample of $m$ draws from the distribution of $\hat \theta_n$, and associated deviations $d_{n,i},\; i \in 1...n$.

What the definition is saying is that the distribution of $\hat \theta_n$, has less and less of its probability in the interval $(-\infty,\theta - \epsilon) \cup (\theta + \epsilon,\infty)$ as $n$ gets bigger. You can see this if you simulate taking a large number $M$ of $n-sample$ means and see how many of these sample means are more than some $\epsilon$ away from the true mean. What you'll see is that as you let $n$ get bigger and bigger, fewer and fewer of these $M$ sample means will be greater than $\epsilon$ away from the the true mean. In fact, you will see this behavior for any value of $\epsilon > 0$ that you choose, no matter how small.

Therefore, for every $\gamma, \epsilon > 0$ we can find some $N_{\gamma}(\epsilon)$ such that $P(D_n > \epsilon) < \gamma \;\;\forall n>N_{\gamma}(\epsilon)$

You can view this statement in terms of the behavior of samples drawn from $\hat \theta_n$ or in terms of the distribution of $\hat \theta_n$ itself. I actually think of the latter, which makes this limit just a plain old limit from calculus applied to the function $P(D_n>\epsilon)$

Comment: Thanks for responding -- every bit helps. However, the question was not about the meaning of consistency. My question is about how one interprets the actual mathematical statement. In particular, does it mean "a value drawn from the distribution" or something else?

Comment: @TonyK you can interpret it from a sampling perspective (i.e., only $p$-percent of sample means of size $n$ will be more than $\epsilon$ away from the population mean) or in terms of the actual distribution function of $\hat \theta_n$, in which case you are just taking the limit of a function (just like in calculus) but the limit is about the probability that your actual sample of size $n$ will be greater than $\epsilon$ away from the true population value. 

Hope that helps -- I updated my post too.

Comment: Thank you for expanding your answer. I realize that the notation in my question is not the best: I should have denoted the estimator as $\hat{\theta_n}$ -- it might have been clearer. I've upticked your answer.

Comment: @TonyK glad it helped! hopefully it addressed your question.